# Ways to create dynamic matrix in C?

Tags: c, matrix, dynamic-arrays

This is the only way I know to create a matrix (2D array) in C, dynamically, and reading user input into its elements:

- Creating a pointer to an array of `x` pointers, where each pointer
  represents a line in the matrix - `x` is the number of lines in the matrix (its height).
- Pointing each pointer in this array to an array with `y` elements,
  where `y` is the number of columns in the matrix (the width).

---

```
int main()
{

  int i, j, lines, columns, **intMatrix;

  printf("Type the matrix lines:\t");
  scanf("%d", &lines);
  printf("Type the matrix columns:\t");
  scanf("%d", &columns);

  intMatrix = (int **)malloc(lines * sizeof(int *)); 
  //pointer to an array of [lines] pointers

  for (i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
      intMatrix[i] = (int *)malloc(columns * sizeof(int)); 
      //pointer to a single array with [columns] integers

  for (i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
  {
      for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
      {
        printf("Type a number for <line: %d, column: %d>\t", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%d", &intMatrix[i][j]);
      }
  }
```

Are there other ways to do this?

Comment: Do you actually need any other way?

Comment: Please read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/multidim-arrays2.html for multidimensional arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try like this

```
int main()
{    
  int i, j, lines, columns, *intMatrix;

  printf("Type the matrix lines:\t");
  scanf("%d", &lines);
  printf("Type the matrix columns:\t");
  scanf("%d", &columns);

  intMatrix = (int *)malloc(lines * columns * sizeof(int)); 

  for (i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
  {
      for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
      {
        printf("Type a number for <line: %d, column: %d>\t", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%d", &intMatrix[i*lines + j]);
      }
  }
```

Comment: How can I pass the matrix to a function in both my example (`**intMatrix`) and yours (`*intMatrix`)? How will I access the matrix elements inside the function? Thanks.

Comment: you can pass to the function as `int *matrix` and then calculate the element as `intMatrix[i*lines + j]` as shown in the example.

Answer (score 3):

From C99 onwards (but not C++), you can use variable length arrays:

```
int main()
{    
  int i, j, lines, columns;

  printf("Type the matrix lines:\t");
  scanf("%d", &lines);
  printf("Type the matrix columns:\t");
  scanf("%d", &columns);

  {
    int intMatrix[lines][columns];

    for (i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
        {
          printf("Type a number for <line: %d, column: %d>\t", i+1, j+1);
          scanf("%d", &intMatrix[i][j]);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Or even like this:

```
void readData (int lines, int columns, int array[lines][columns])
{
  int i, j;

  for (i = 0; i < lines; ++i)
  {
      for (j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
      {
        printf("Type a number for <line: %d, column: %d>\t", i+1, j+1);
        scanf("%d", &array[i][j]);
      }
  }
}

int main()
{
  int lines, columns;

  printf("Type the matrix lines:\t");
  scanf("%d", &lines);
  printf("Type the matrix columns:\t");
  scanf("%d", &columns);

  {
    int intMatrix[lines][columns];

    readData (lines, columns, intMatrix);
  }
}
```

But, in both cases, the array data is all stored on the stack, not the heap, so there's no way to store it properly, and you can't put it in a struct or anything malloc'd.

Comment: Is C99 popular in C programming nowadays? (I'm currently using C85) but I don't know what real C programmers use today (in the industry).

Comment: There's a C85? I'm aware of C89 (aka C90), C99, and C11. Real code uses whatever the compiler allows, standard or otherwise. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
struct matrix {
    type *mem;
};

struct matrix* matrix_new () {
    struct matrix *M = malloc (sizeof(matrix));
    M->mem = malloc (sizeof (type) * rows * cols);
    return M;
}
```

use `realloc`,`memcpy`,`memmove` and `free` to modify chunks of the array. To access single elemnts use something like `mem[row*cols+col]` or `mem[rows*col+row]` depend on what has priority for you (or what you define a row and a column).